# How to vertically align filename on file input in IE8

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, file-upload, internet-explorer-8

I have a page with a FileUpload control rendered dynamically. At runtime, Asp generates the following input:

```html
<input name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$ucPF$ucCustomField2$field2" id="field2" 
       type="file" Validators="[object HTMLSpanElement]" 
       cachedHoverStateItem="[object Object]"/>
```

In Google Chrome, the display seems to be spot on:

[image: Google Chrome display image]

However, in IE8, not so much:

[image: Internet Explorer 8 display image]

I know it's a small detail, but it still bothers me unreasonably. Any one of you would happen to know why the text is not vertically aligned and what can I do to fix it? Perhaps it's not a normal behaviour and I'm doing something wrong on my end?

I have tried adding the following CSS:

```css
input[type="file"] {
    line-height: 1ex;
}
```

But it didn't change anything.

Comment: Try padding for your input. same padding on the top as the bottom.

Comment: @Andrew [I wish it was that easy..](http://i.imgur.com/kymiIG3.png). But nope, IE8.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

File inputs are actually platform dependent and there is no standard way to style them... I've worked with them in the past and what most people tend to do is create an invisible file input and a separate text-input/button combi. The on-click of the button then triggers the on-click of the file input, and after the file input has a value it is copied to the text-input via Javascript.

Something like this (pseudo-code):

```
<input type="file" id="file" style="visibility:hidden" onchange="setFile(this.files[0])" />
<input type="text" id="filename">
<button onclick="document.getElementById('file').click()" />
```

With something like this in Javascript:

```
function setFile(file) {
    var input = document.getElementById("filename");
    input.value = file.name;
}
```

The code above asserts you're only supporting browsers which support the new (in progress draft) of the File API, there will certainly be ways to do this for older browsers as well...

---

Another approach (which works for older browsers) is described [here](http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/inputfile.html)

Answer (score 0):

```
input[type="file"] {
    line-height: 1ex;
}
```

Is this the line height of your text box? I thought `ex` indicated the height of the letter itself. Try adding the height of the actual box.

Comment: Yes, I first tried putting 10px, and it didn't work any better. The reason I then changed for 1ex is that it is supposed to work even though the text size is changed.